# Trying to change label using entry box and button

Tags: python, button, tkinter, label, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to make a label that will change when I enter text into the entry box and click the button.

I've tried doing some research but can't seem to find out how to do it    .

```
 from tkinter import *

 master = Tk()
 master.title("Part 3")

 v = StringVar()
 v.set("Please change me")

 lb= Label(master, textvariable=v, fg="red",bg="black").grid(row=0,column=0)
 ent= Entry(master, textvariable=v,).grid(row=1,column=2)
 b1= Button(master, text="Click to change", fg="red",bg="black").grid(row=1,column=0)
```

Comment: These are similar questions all over StackOverflow -- [here's one I answered recently](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29056637/736937).  You start by registering a callback with a button the `command` keyword argument to the constructor.

Comment: The way you have it set up now, the data will change immediately as you type. Is that what you want, or do you only want it to update when you click a button?

Comment: I want it to change when I click the button, I have only managed to get it to work the way I did.

Answer (score 1):

to do so, you first need to define a callback that changes the value. (example below)

You should also use two Variables of type StringVar to store the different Values

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.title("Part 3")

lText = StringVar()
lText.set("Please change me")

eText = StringVar()

def ChangeLabelText(event=None):
    global lText
    global eText
    lText.set(eText.get())
```

Then, bind the callback to the button

```
lb  = Label(master, textvariable=lText, fg="red",bg="black").grid(row=0,column=0)
ent = Entry(master, textvariable=eText).grid(row=1,column=2)
b1  = Button(master, text="Click to change", fg="red",bg="black", command=ChangeLabelText).grid(row=1,column=0)
```